# input to div sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have such code:

```
<div style="width:500; height:500;">
    <input type="button"/>
</div>
```

how to fit the button to the div's sizes?
if its imposible ny css, i can use js,jquery

Comment: fit means height and width of button should be same as div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you give your width and height of parent container a unit suffix on the value:

```
<div style="width:500px;height:500px;">
    <input type="button" style="width:100%;height:100%;"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css for this

```
<input type="button" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;" />
```

Better use a class for that

```
.inpbutton
{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}

<input type="button" class="inpbutton" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you can start by something like this...

HTML:

```
<div style="width:500; height:500;">
    <input class="expand" type="button"/>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('.expand').each(function(i) {
        $(this).width($(this).parent().width());
        $(this).height($(this).parent().height());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('input[type=button]').each(function(){
        $(this).height($(this).parent().height());
        $(this).width($(this).parent().width());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is getting the button to fill out the div why not remove one of the elements, making either the div act as a button by putting whatever action you want on it's onclick, or just setting the button as the main element with a size.

Might be that you need both, but unless there's a reason you need both, there's no point wrapping the button in a div a you'll just get more elements than needed.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just put the size on the button instead of the div? The div would automatically take on the correct size, and you'll get a perfect fit, without JS.